# How to update video's current time when new video is loaded with Tauri and Svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, video, svelte, tauri

I'm currently creating a windows app with Tauri and Svelte, but ran into some problem. I have a button which when clicked opens the file system to allow a new video to be selected. When a new video is selected I update the VideoStore with the new path. This all works great, and with the below code the video then updates to show the new video, however I also want to reset **time = 0** so that the new video starts from the beginning, but that isn't happening here. So if the previous video was at 20 seconds when a new file is being selected, the new video also starts at 20 seconds.

When clicking the Reset button the time changes back to 0, but I would like it to also happen automatically when VideoStore gets updated and the new video is loaded.

I update the **time** when **$VideoStore** changes and time is bound to the video's **currentTime**:

```js
    $: {
        time = 0;
        video_src = `https://asset.localhost/${$VideoStore}`;
    }
```

**The full code:**

`Video.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import VideoStore from "../stores/VideoStore";

    let video_src = $VideoStore;

    let time = 0;
    let duration;
    let paused = true;

    const skip = () => {
        time += 10;
    };

    function resetTime() {
        time = 0;
    }

    $: {
        time = 0;
        video_src = `https://asset.localhost/${$VideoStore}`;
    }
</script>

<p>{time}</p>
<button on:click={resetTime}>Reset</button>
<button on:click={skip}>Skip 10 seconds</button>
<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-media-has-caption -->
<div class="player">
    {#key video_src}
        <video
            src={video_src}
            width="1280"
            height="720"
            bind:currentTime={time}
            bind:duration
            bind:paused
            controls
        >
        </video>
    {/key}
</div>
```

`OpenButton.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { open } from "@tauri-apps/api/dialog";
    import { documentDir } from "@tauri-apps/api/path";

    import VideoStore from "../stores/VideoStore";

    let filename = "";

    const openfile = async () => {
        const selected = await open({
            directory: false,
            multiple: false,
            defaultPath: await documentDir(),
        });

        filename = selected.replace(/\\/g, "/");
        VideoStore.update(() => {
            return filename;
        });
    };
</script>

<button on:click={openfile}>Open File</button>
```

Comment: You can just use `set` instead of `update` if you do not need the previous value, by the way.

Comment: Why are you recreating the video element with `#key`? Also, the time should reset to 0 automatically when the source changes ([Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/41bb2ef43a224b6e9b4473ab7218e94a?version=3.49.0)).

Comment: @H.B. I think I added `#key` at first because the videos weren't updating properly at first. But you're right, when I took it out it solved the issue. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @H.B. I also tried changing `update` to `set`, however then the videos don't update anymore. Any idea why that is?

Comment: `set` takes the object directly, not a function, it should have the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#key` probably causes the new instance of the `video` to be initialized with the old time value. If a `src` is switched without recreating the element, the time will automatically reset to 0.

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/41bb2ef43a224b6e9b4473ab7218e94a?version=3.49.0)